# Sharing variable in two closures

Tags: rust

I'm listening to user input in an [gtk-rs](https://gtk-rs.org/) input element. `input.connect_changed` triggers when the input changes and `input.connect_activate` triggers when Enter is pressed.

```
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow};
use std::process::{Command, Output};

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("com.jwestall.ui-demo")
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(build_ui);
    app.run();
}

fn run_command(command: &str) -> Output {
    Command::new("sh")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg(command)
        .output()
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("failed to execute {}'", command))
}

fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let input = gtk::Entry::builder()
        .placeholder_text("input")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("gtk-app")
        .child(&input)
        .build();

    window.show_all();

    input.connect_changed(|entry| {
        let input_text = entry.text();

        let command = format!("xdotool search --onlyvisible --name {}", input_text);
        let window_id_output = run_command(&command);

        if window_id_output.status.success() {
            println!(
                "stdout: {}",
                String::from_utf8_lossy(&window_id_output.stdout)
            );
        } else {
            println!(
                "sterr: {}",
                String::from_utf8_lossy(&window_id_output.stderr)
            );
        }
    });

    input.connect_activate(move |entry| {
        let input_text = entry.text();

        // // `xdotool windowactivate` doesn't produce any output
        let command = format!("xdotool windowactivate {}", window_id_output);
        let window_activate_output = run_command(&command);

        println!("window_activate: {}", window_activate_output);

        window.hide();
        window.close();
    });
}
```

I want to set `window_id_output` in `input.connect_changed`, then use it in `input.connect_activate` (in the `xdotool windowactivate {}` command).

How can I use `window_id_output` this way in these two closures?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b015a73404281a1710a327fe5fea8b48)

Comment: If I remember correctly, GTK runs all event handlers in the main thread, so you don't need any locking. The only requirments on your closures is that they are `'static` – you don't need `Send` or `Sync`. Wrapping `window_id_output` in `Rc<RefCell<…>>` should be all you need.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Could you give me an example? I tried using `Rc<RefCell<...>>`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5bd1af161465a24ae12741fc59b98ab. But it's producing compiling errors like: `move occurs because `window_id_output_rc` has type `Rc<RefCell<Option│
<Output>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait`.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on `Rc` and `RefCell` in the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sven Marnach said, you can use `Rc<RefCell<..>>` to move data between closures.

The simplest example is probably [this one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=886a89908644635ec095fd506d3cf1c0), probably how the gtk event loop works anyways:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(0));
    
    let a_ref = Rc::clone(&a);
    let closure_1 = move || {
        let mut a = a_ref.borrow_mut();
        *a += 1;
        println!("closure_1: {}", &a);
    };
    
    let a_ref = Rc::clone(&a);
    let closure_2 = move || {
        let a = a_ref.borrow();
        println!("closure_2: {}", &a);
    };
    
    for _ in 1..10 {
        closure_1();
        closure_2();
    }
}
```

For your specific case, see a reduced example below (based on your code):

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow};

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("com.jwestall.ui-demo")
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(build_ui);
    app.run();
}

fn process(s: &str) -> String {
    format!("you entered '{}'", s)
}

fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let input = gtk::Entry::builder()
        .placeholder_text("input")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("gtk-app")
        .child(&input)
        .build();

    window.show_all();

    let shared_var = Rc::new(RefCell::new(String::new()));
    let shared_var_ref = Rc::clone(&shared_var);
    input.connect_changed(move |entry| {
        let input_text = entry.text();
        let mut shared = shared_var_ref.borrow_mut();
        *shared = process(&input_text);
    });

    let shared_var_ref = Rc::clone(&shared_var);
    input.connect_activate(move |_entry| {
        let shared = shared_var_ref.borrow();
        println!("{}", shared);

        window.hide();
        window.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm new to `Rc` and `RefCell`. I'll have to read more about them.